# Mysql reverse pattern matching - alternative?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, pattern-matching

Lets say I have the following values in a MySQL database table:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```

I am looking for a fast way to retrieve all values that are a prefix of my input. Obviously this works:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'abcde12345' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%');
```

...but is very slow on large datasets.
Are there any smarter ways of storing the data to enable fast lookups?

Comment: So in this case your input is `'abcde12345'` and your result should be `{a
ab, abc, abcd}` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza exactly!

Comment: You can try Willem suggestion, do you create an index for `col` ?

Comment: Thanks, I just did, there is an index for col, speed-wise its pretty much identical.

Comment: You probably show rewrite your question. Right now the only way to do this is a full table scan. Maybe if you explain your problem we can think on other way to optimize this. Like some partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* help, along with `INDEX(col)`:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table
    WHERE  col BETWEEN 'a' AND 'abcde12345'
      AND  'abcde12345' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%');
```

This is more likely:

```
SELECT *
    FROM  table
    WHERE col IN ('a', 'ab', 'abc', ..., 'abcde12345');
```

The latter version *could* be constructed with code from `'abcde12345'`, or (more painfully) in a Stored Procedure.